# FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, selenium4

I am trying to Page object Model project in maven using selenium with java and Testng and i have added all the dependency in pom.xml but after running the script i am facing some problem saying FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp and i have to update the project and i have checked my script my times but still i am not able solve this issue.

`This is Base Class`

```
package com.qa.Pages;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerOptions;

public class Base 
{
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop;

    public Base()
    {
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("./Configuration/config.properties");
            prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(fis);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Property File not loaded Properly " +e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public static void browserFactory()
    {
        String BrowserName = prop.getProperty("browser");

        if(BrowserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

        else if(BrowserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",prop.getProperty("firefoxpath"));
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        else if(BrowserName.equalsIgnoreCase("ie"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",prop.getProperty("ie"));
            InternetExplorerOptions opt = new InternetExplorerOptions();
            opt.ignoreZoomSettings();
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(opt);
        }

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
    }


}
```

`This is pageclass`

```
package com.qa.Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class Homepage extends Base
{
    public Homepage()
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[@id = '1st']")
    WebElement howItWorksTab;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[@id = '2nd']")
    WebElement hiringManagerTab;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'Get Certified')]")
    WebElement getCertifiedTab;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"bs-example-navbar-collapse-1\"]/ul[1]/li[4]/span/a")
    WebElement pricing;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'Learn More')]")
    WebElement learnMore;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"main-md-content\"]/div[1]/section/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/button")
    WebElement getStarted1;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"main-md-content\"]/div[1]/section/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/button")
    WebElement getStarted2;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'CONTACT US')]")
    WebElement contactUsLink;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'About Us')]")
    WebElement aboutUsLink;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'Blog')]")
    WebElement blogLink;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'Privacy Policy')]")
    WebElement privacyPolicyLink;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'Complex Adaptive Testing')]")
    WebElement complexAdaptiveLink;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'FAQ')]")
    WebElement faqLink;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'//*[@id=\"main-md-content\"]/div[2]/footer/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/a[2]')]")
    WebElement pricingLink;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"main-md-content\"]/div[2]/footer/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/a[3]")
    WebElement howItWorksLink;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'Geekbears')]")
    WebElement geeksbearsLink;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//button[contains(text(),'Log in')]")
    WebElement logInBtn;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//button[contains(text(),'Sign up')]")
    WebElement signUpBtn;


    public void hoveronHowItWorksTab()
    {
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(howItWorksTab).build().perform();
    }

    public void hoveroverHiringManager()
    {
        Actions  act = new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(hiringManagerTab).build().perform();
    }

    public void hoverOverGetCertified()
    {
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(getCertifiedTab).build().perform();
    }

    public void hoverOverPricing()
    {
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(pricing).build().perform();
    }

    public void clickOnLearnMore()
    {
        learnMore.click();
    }

    public void clickOnGetStarted()
    {
        getStarted1.click();
    }

    public void clickOnGetStarted2()
    {
        getStarted2.click();
    }

    public void clickOnContactUsLink()
    {
        contactUsLink.click();
    }

    public void clickOnAboutusLink()
    {
        aboutUsLink.click();
    }

    public void clickOnBlogLink()
    {
        blogLink.click();
    }

    public void clickOnPrivacyPolicyLink()
    {
        privacyPolicyLink.click();
    }

    public void clickOnComplexAdaptiveLink()
    {
        complexAdaptiveLink.click();
    }

    public void clickOnFAQlink()
    {
        faqLink.click();
    }

    public void clickOnPricingLink()
    {
        pricingLink.click();
    }

    public void clickOnHowItWorksLink()
    {
        howItWorksLink.click();
    }

    public void clickOnGeeksBearsLink()
    {
        geeksbearsLink.click();
    }

    public void clickOnLoginLink()
    {
        logInBtn.click();
    }

    public void clickOnSignUpLink()
    {
        signUpBtn.click();
    }

}
```

`This is Test Class`

```
package com.qa.test;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.qa.Pages.Base;
import com.qa.Pages.Homepage;

public class HomepageTest extends Base
{
    Homepage home;


    public HomepageTest()
    {
        super();
    }
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp()  
    {

        home = new Homepage();
        browserFactory();
    }
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void mouseHoverHowItWorksTest()
    {
        home.hoveronHowItWorksTab();
    }
    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void mouseHoverHiringManagerTest()
    {
        home.hoveroverHiringManager();
    }
    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void mouseHoverOnGetCertifiedTest()
    {
        home.hoverOverGetCertified();
    }
    @Test(priority = 4)
    public void mouseHoverOnPricing()
    {
        home.hoverOverPricing();
    }





    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

`This is the Error Log`

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-3', revision: '8c567de6dc'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-L95KUEC', ip: '192.168.1.49', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.117, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b3389..., userDataDir: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:56007}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 1e0d7d8e81fe5268218a38952f31c2cc
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:52)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:576)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:276)
    at com.qa.Pages.Base.browserFactory(Base.java:61)
    at com.qa.test.HomepageTest.setUp(HomepageTest.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:589)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:822)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1130)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
```

`This Pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>devdatascholarautomation</groupId>
  <artifactId>devdatascholarautomation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-snapshot</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>devdatascholarautomation</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceencoding>utf-8</project.build.sourceencoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-3</version>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using POM design pattern. `I am trying to Page object Model project` and  `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);` differs also you have not provided pom.xml. please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Yes sir I am using POM design pattern and i have also added the POM.xml file, So sir please help me out with this